# Decimal value is coming as 0E-8

Tags: java, xml, validation, xsd, weblogic12c

we are validating XML with XSD in java 1.8 and web logic 12c,But we are facing 0E-8 is not a valid value for decimal

Below is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<isns:Envelope xmlns:isns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
               xmlns:pkp-core="http://tracx.de/pkp/interfaces/core/1.0"
               xmlns:pkp-msg="http://tracx.de/pkp/interfaces/msg/1.0">
   <isns:Header/>
   <isns:Body>
      <pkp-msg:ABC>
         <pkp-msg:test>
            <pkp-core:oops>
               <pkp-core:XYZ>0.00000000</pkp-core:XYZ>
               
             <pkp-core:billi>period</pkp-core:bill>
               <pkp-core:check>0.90225</pkp-core:check>
            </pkp-core:oops>
         </pkp-msg:test>
      </pkp-msg:ABC>
   </isns:Body>
</isns:Envelope>
```

piece of java code :

```
javax.xml.validation.Validator validator = schema.newValidator();

                validator.setErrorHandler(new EUBatchValidationHandler());

                validator.validate(source);
```

Comment: `0.00000000` when parse by `BigDecimal` is a numeric `0` with a scale of 8, as it should be, but the [`toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#toString--) method of `BigDecimal` outputs that as `0E-8`, which is well-documented. You didn't specify *why* that value is being rejected; is it because a value of **zero** in not valid, or is it because the value is not allowed to use [**Scientific Notation**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation)? What does the actual **XML schema** specify?

Comment: hi @Andreas. in XSD we have validation like                                              <xsd:element name="XYZ" type="xsd:decimal">

Comment: Don't explain the XSD, show it, *in the question*. Just the relevant part is enough.

Comment: *FYI:* The value `0.00000000` is a valid `xsd:decimal` value, so either you don't have what you think you have, or the XSD Validator is bugged.

Comment: we are using the above validate method in java 1.6 it is working fine ,issues with java 1.8.so any alternative method u can suggest please

Comment: I see no issues with java 1.8. Check your assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

**Unable to Reproduce**
*This is not an answer, but is written as such, so it can include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).*

The following code has been tested on:

- OpenJDK jdk1.7.0_75
- Oracle jdk1.8.0_181
- OpenJDK jdk-11.0.2
- OpenJDK jdk-14

The code produce the same output on all 4.

```java
import java.io.StringReader;

import javax.xml.XMLConstants;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
import javax.xml.validation.Schema;
import javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory;
import javax.xml.validation.Validator;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String xml = "<ABC>\n" +
                     "  <XYZ>0.00000000</XYZ>\n" +
                     "</ABC>";
        DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder domBuilder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document document = domBuilder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)));
        System.out.println("XYZ = " + document.getElementsByTagName("XYZ").item(0).getTextContent());
        
        String xsd = "<schema xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\">\n" + 
                     "  <element name=\"ABC\">\n" + 
                     "    <complexType>\n" + 
                     "      <sequence>\n" + 
                     "        <element name=\"XYZ\" type=\"decimal\" />\n" + 
                     "      </sequence>\n" + 
                     "    </complexType>\n" + 
                     "  </element>\n" + 
                     "</schema>";
        SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
        Schema schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(new StreamSource(new StringReader(xsd)));
        Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
        validator.validate(new DOMSource(document));
        System.out.println("Validation successful");
    }
}
```

*Output*

```
XYZ = 0.00000000
Validation successful
```

Comment: thank you so much  it clear all my doudts @Andreas